# What is meaning of the phrase "should be the way to go"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase "should be the way to go"?

I haven't been able to figure anything out from searching online. The wording originally appeared in a block of text like this:

> Honestly, just using the language is the best way, as far as I know. Talk to people in English, and try to pay attention to the way they speak and the words they use. If someone uses a word you're not familiar with, keep it in mind and consider trying to use it when applicable. There's not much point learning words that you won't use, or words that will confuse people when you do use them. So just learning from others, in theory, **should be the way to go.**"

Comment: 'This is the way to go' means 'This is what you should do.' 'This should be the way to go' means 'Try this. But don't blame me if it doesn't work.'

Answer (score 4):

[**the way to go**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/way_to_go):

> A route, course of action; **a preferred decision or choice**.
>   *"They are about the same quality, so if you can get a discount on the color you like, that would be the way to go."*

---

Definition from wiktionary; emphasis mine

Comment: Would it not be better to distinguish the literal use from the metaphorical?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain it intuitively:

> So just learning from others, in theory, should be the way to go."

"This is the way to go" = "This is how to do it", "This is how it should be done"

Like from many *ways* how to do it, this is the one that is *the* best.

> So just learning from others, in theory, should be the option to choose."

Answer (score 0):

Modus operandi, preferred alternative, course of action, best way

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

'It should be the way to go' is meant as 'it should work' or 'it should get the work done'.

Answer (score 0):

means "Should be the approach to use"

[Merriam Webster **Way** n.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way)

**4a: manner or method of doing or happening**

*admired her way of thinking*

**also : method of accomplishing : MEANS**

*that's the way to do it*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Would you understand it better if I said ***...should be the path to follow...***.

This is an older idiom which means exactly the same thing.